# Changing select output block from probabilities to conditions based on patient symptoms in AnyLogic

Tags: conditional-statements, anylogic

I am working on a simulation model in AnyLogic, specifically in the healthcare domain. Currently, I have a select output block that uses probabilities to determine the process flow for patients. However, I would like to modify it to use conditions based on the symptoms patients are experiencing. I have two main questions:

1. How can I change the select output block to use conditions instead of probabilities? I want the process flow to be determined based on specific symptoms that patients exhibit. Do I need to write code for this, or is there a built-in functionality in AnyLogic to handle this?
2. Additionally, I would like the patients to be randomly assigned symptoms. This means that each patient would have a random set of symptoms when they arrive. How can I implement this randomness in assigning symptoms to patients within AnyLogic?

Thank you in advance for your help!

Comment: Study the step-by-step tutorials first. They show these and many other important basic concepts (even when they are not healthcare specific, this is irrelevant for your problem) -> https://anylogic.help/tutorials/index.html

Comment: Also, welcome to SOF. This place works best for you if you ask very focused, specific questions on 1 AnyLogic issue, show exactly what you tried already and where you are stuck. If you want to know “how do I best do X in AnyLogic”, you should use the LinkedIn forum instead. Check this overview to the community to understand why: https://benjamin-schumann.com/blog/anylogic-community. Welcome again, happy to help